# Searching for a result based on a trigger

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula that searches for the deadline of a particular task within a table. The formula is built using repetitive IF functions; if cell contains '1', but the following cell is empty, this must mean the deadline date was the cell with 1 in it, thus returning that date.

However, the formula is very long. I will display this on a sample spreadsheet. The real spreadsheet in use mimics this layout, however, is much larger (H4:FZ243), with this lengthy function copied over the 243 rows, so the spreadsheet is severely slowed by operating the function as it is currently written.

The screenshot below shows the smaller data sample, but gives you an idea of the function being used. This is a link to the SS: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oz4ULeq2BMQCQi08bqb6RGgTgjLIaw364cTb7J8W6fk/edit?usp=sharing

[image: https://i.ibb.co/Yk3dQYb/SO1.jpg]

Can anyone suggest a method to drastically cut down this function but still produce the same results?

Comment: shouldn't be D4: 24/05/2019 ???

Comment: Yes, I suppose if the first deadline has passed (which was 13th May), the second deadline would be picked up (24th May). My current formula is good enough to cover this unfortunately, but if you have a suggestion to resolve this too, that would be great.